# Option to save chart as pdf or image when using GetOrgChart

Tags: getorgchart

I am using GetOrgChart to generate the organizational chart, please suggest how to save the chart out put in image or pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable this flag - 'enablePrint' to true and you will get a print icon on the header of the OrgChart. Using this you can save your OrgChart in PDF format

http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#enablePrint

Here is the fiddle-
http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/jgqyh81a/

`var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{

            enablePrint: true,
            dataSource: [
            { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie"},
            { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field"},
            { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson"}]
        });`